# Powershell renaming files not working - no error

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to copy files from one directory to another and rename them. The destination folder's files are deleted and the files copy but unfortunately the rename part of my script isn't doing anything. There are no errors being displayed.

```
#Set variables
[string]$source = "C:\temp\Photos\Original\*"
[string]$destination = "C:\temp\Photos\Moved\"
#Delete original files to avoid conflicts
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
#Copy from source to destination
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $source -Destination $destination

Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include *.jpg | rename-item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-', ' ' }
```

At the moment I am simply trying to replace hyphens with spaces but I will also need to remove a `W` from the end of the filename, when I can get it to work.

Example original filename: `First-Last-W.jpg`

Example desired filename: `First Last.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a `$PSItem` (also referenced as `$_`) outside of the proper context. You should add a `Foreach-Object` to your pipeline:

```
# This can be a one-liner, but made it multiline for clarity
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Filter *.jpg | Foreach-Object {
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ( ( $_.Name -Replace '-w\.jpg$', '.jpg' ) -Replace '-', ' ' )
}
```

Two additional things I added to your code block above:

1. You used curly-braces where you should have used parentheses as evidenced in @Jacob's answer. I fixed this here as well.
2. I added a second `-Replace` that will remove a `-W` from the end of the new name (while keeping the `.jpg` extension). For more information about Powershell regular expression matching, see the sources below.

Sources:

- Basic Powershell regex examples - https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/
- .NET Regular Expression Syntax - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: That will not work, there is no `-W` left after replacing `-` with a space reverse the order of the replace. Also `Rename-Item` **does** accept piped input and using a script block is the proper way. Inside a script block you **have to** use `$_.Property` to reference the currently processed piped objects properties. Your script will fail because you neither pipe $_ to the Rename-Item nor specify a `-Path`. You should test your scripts if not 100% sure they do what you expect.

Comment: I did test it but accidentally reversed the regex above. Thanks for spotting that

Comment: `Rename-Item` has still no Object to rename. Either `$_ | Rename-Item ...` or `Rename-Item -Path $_ ...`

Comment: I swear I had the `$PSItem`, must have removed it by mistake. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks - this worked but I had to use `-filter` rather than `-include` as per one of the other answers

Comment: Not sure why `-Include` didn't work, even the `help` on `Get-ChildItem` insinuates that should work.

Answer (score 3):

change `-include` param with `-filter`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include *.jpg
```

include is based cmdlet

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -filter *.jpg
```

filter is based-provider

[for more info](https://tfl09.blogspot.com/2012/02/get-childitem-and-theinclude-and-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but it looks those curly braces look wrong, what happens if you try the following:

```
#Set variables
[string]$source = "C:\temp\Photos\Original\*"
[string]$destination = "C:\temp\Photos\Moved\"
#Delete original files to avoid conflicts
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
#Copy from source to destination
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $source -Destination $destination

Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Include *.jpg | rename-item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '-', ' ')
```

Comment: Error: `Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string. At line:9 char:72`